# Error authenticating with Azure using node sdk:

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-node-sdk

I am following the tutorial [Windows Azure SDK for Node.js - Compute Management](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/lib/services/computeManagement/README.md) to manage virtual machines.

I downloaded the pem file using `azure account cert export` to `<Subscription GUID>.pem`.

The script currently contains:

```
var subscriptionId ="<Subscription GUID>";
var pem = "<Subscription GUID>.pem";

var computeManagementClient = computeManagement.createComputeManagementClient(computeManagement.createCertificateCloudCredentials({
    subscriptionId: subscriptionId,
    pem: fs.readFileSync(pem)
}));
```

And when I run it from Node.js it produces the error:

```
C:\Apps\azure\node_modules\azure-mgmt-compute\node_modules\azure-common\lib\util\validate.js:416
  throw new Error('Required argument ' + name + ' for function ' + func + ' is
        ^
Error: Required argument credentials.pem for function CertificateCloudCredentials is not defined
    at throwMissingArgument (C:\Apps\azure\node_modules\azure-mgmt-compute\node_modules\azure-common\lib\util\validate.js:416:9)
    at ArgumentValidator._.extend.string (C:\Apps\azure\node_modules\azure-mgmt-compute\node_modules\azure-common\lib\util\validate.js:426:7)
    at C:\Apps\azure\node_modules\azure-mgmt-compute\node_modules\azure-common\lib\services\credentials\certificateCloudCredentials.js:35:9
    at Object.validateArgs (C:\Apps\azure\node_modules\azure-mgmt-compute\node_modules\azure-common\lib\util\validate.js:478:3)
    at new CertificateCloudCredentials (C:\Apps\azure\node_modules\azure-mgmt-compute\node_modules\azure-common\lib\services\credentials\certificateCloudCredentials.js:32:14)
    at Object.exports.createCertificateCloudCredentials (C:\Apps\azure\node_modules\azure-mgmt-compute\lib\compute.js:54:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Apps\azure\setup.js:14:97)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is with `pem: fs.readFileSync(pem)`. The SDK is not converting the node buffer to a string. There is an [issue on Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/issues/1137).

Until this is fixed use `toString` on the buffer:

```
pem: fs.readFileSync(pem).toString()
```